# git take theirs/ours AND successfully merged code

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Suppose there is conflict when rebasing a `feature` Git branch on a `master` Git branch:

```
git init
echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive" > foo
git add foo
git commit -m a

echo -e "ONE\ntwo\nTHREE\nfour\nfive" > foo
git commit -a -m b

git checkout -b feature HEAD^
echo -e "One\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nFive" > foo
git commit -a -m c

git rebase master
```

The conflicting file `foo` is:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
ONE
=======
One
>>>>>>> c
two
THREE
four
Five
```

How can I obtain from command line the file `foo_master` containing the
sucessfull merge (`THREE` and `Five`), and is case of conflict, the `master`
code (`ONE`):

```
ONE
two
THREE
four
Five
```

Note that it is different from `git checkout --ours foo`, which does not contains the
modificatoin from `feature` successfully applied (`Five`):

```
ONE
two
THREE
four
five
```

I would also like to have the counterpart file `foo_feature` containing the
`feature` code in case of conflict, but with the modificatons from `master`
that are successfully applied (`ONE`):

```
One
two
THREE
four
Five
```

My goal is then to vertically `vimdiff` the files `foo_master` and
`foo_feature` to solve the conflict.

Comment: I think I'll use sed to remove parts between `<<<<<<<` and `=======`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git merge-file`, twice, with `--ours` in one case and `--theirs` in the other.  (Note that these are not the same as `-s ours` but more like `-X ours`, but they apply only to one set of three input files.)

You will need all three input files, but they are available during a conflicted merge, as all three are in the index, at stage 1 (base), 2 (ours), and 3 (theirs).  Use `git checkout-index --stage=all` to extract all three at once.  Note that this implies `--temp`, so that you get three file names printed, containing the three copies of the three input files, copied out of the index, into a usable format.

(This is how `git mergetool` obtains the three copies of the files to feed to an external merge tool such as vimdiff.)

Comment: Perfect and powerful! I didn't know these two commands (`merge-file`, `checkout-index`). Thanks!